# How to make right aligned text within a td all start at the same point without using any class?

Tags: html, frontend

A part of the html below is a table with a single row displaying shipping and invoice sections side by side. I need to have lines in the invoice section all to start at the same point as shown in the image below.

[image]

The full HTML is here:

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>Shipped From:</strong><br />
                Jerdon Style, LLC<br />
                Richardson, TX, 75081<br />
                US<br />
            </td>
            <td text-align="left" align="right">
                <strong>Invoice Number</strong>: 110697<br />
                <span style="color:#F00"><strong>Invoice Date</strong>: Wed Jun 30, 2021, 3:13 PM</span><br />
                <strong>Purpose of Shipment</strong>: Retail Sale<br />
                <strong>Currency of Value</strong>: USD<br />
                <strong>Carrier</strong>: FedEx
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr style="font-weight:bold;font-size:.8em;">
            <th width="10%">SKU</th>
            <th width="30%">DESCRIPTION</th>
            <th width="9%">HS CODE</th>
            <th width="12%">ORIGIN CRITERION</th>
            <th width="12%">COUNRY OF ORIGIN</th>
            <th width="9%">QUANTITY</th>
            <th width="9%">UNIT PRICE</th>
            <th width="9%">TOTAL PRICE</th>
        </tr> 
        <tr class="row1">
            <td>J2020C</td>
            <td>Jerdon 8.25" x 6.5", 5X/1X Wall Mirror, Chrome/White</td>
            <td>700992</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>China</td>
            <td>1 ea.</td>
            <td>$37.67</td>
            <td>$37.67</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row1">
            <td>JRT8500NL</td>
            <td>Sharper Image 8x/1x Reversible LED Lighted Makeup Mirror, Nickel</td>
            <td>700992</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>China</td>
            <td>1 ea.</td>
            <td>$67.97</td>
            <td>$67.97</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `display: contents;` for the second `td`:

And It is good idea to set `width` for first `td` too

```html
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:50%">
                <strong>Shipped From:</strong><br />
                Jerdon Style, LLC<br />
                Richardson, TX, 75081<br />
                US<br />
            </td>
            <td text-align="left" align="right" style="display: contents;">
                <strong>Invoice Number</strong>: 110697<br />
                <span style="color:#F00"><strong>Invoice Date</strong>: Wed Jun 30, 2021, 3:13 PM</span><br />
                <strong>Purpose of Shipment</strong>: Retail Sale<br />
                <strong>Currency of Value</strong>: USD<br />
                <strong>Carrier</strong>: FedEx
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table border="1" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr style="font-weight:bold;font-size:.8em;">
            <th width="10%">SKU</th>
            <th width="30%">DESCRIPTION</th>
            <th width="9%">HS CODE</th>
            <th width="12%">ORIGIN CRITERION</th>
            <th width="12%">COUNRY OF ORIGIN</th>
            <th width="9%">QUANTITY</th>
            <th width="9%">UNIT PRICE</th>
            <th width="9%">TOTAL PRICE</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row1">
            <td>J2020C</td>
            <td>Jerdon 8.25" x 6.5", 5X/1X Wall Mirror, Chrome/White</td>
            <td>700992</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>China</td>
            <td>1 ea.</td>
            <td>$37.67</td>
            <td>$37.67</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row1">
            <td>JRT8500NL</td>
            <td>Sharper Image 8x/1x Reversible LED Lighted Makeup Mirror, Nickel</td>
            <td>700992</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>China</td>
            <td>1 ea.</td>
            <td>$67.97</td>
            <td>$67.97</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: It works almost fine, but I want the invoice section to be right aligned, meaning it should be close to the edge of the second td.